# Regex to remove all (non numeric OR period)

Tags: c#, regex

I need for text like "joe ($3,004.50)" to be filtered down to 3004.50 but am terrible at regex and can't find a suitable solution.  So only numbers and periods should stay - everything else filtered.  I use C# and VS.net 2008 framework 3.5

Answer (score 211, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string s = "joe ($3,004.50)";
s = Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9.]", "");
```

Comment: What about `joe.smith ($3,004.50)`?  Simply removing offending character classes can go quite wrong.

Comment: I make one small correction: `Regex.Replace(s, "[^$0-9.]", "");` You want to leave dollar sign.

Answer (score 42):

The regex is:

```
[^0-9.]
```

You can cache the regex:

```
Regex not_num_period = new Regex("[^0-9.]")
```

then use:

```
string result = not_num_period.Replace("joe ($3,004.50)", "");
```

However, you should keep in mind that some cultures have different conventions for writing monetary amounts, such as: 3.004,50.

Answer (score 4):

You are dealing with a string - string is an `IEumerable<char>`, so you can use LINQ:

```
var input = "joe ($3,004.50)";
var result = String.Join("", input.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.'));

Console.WriteLine(result);   // 3004.50
```

Answer (score 2):

For the accepted answer, MatthewGunn raises a valid point in that all digits, commas, and periods in the entire string will be condensed together. This will avoid that:

```
string s = "joe.smith ($3,004.50)";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?:^|[^w.,])(\d[\d,.]+)(?=\W|$)/)");
Match m = r.match(s);
string v = null;
if (m.Success) {
  v = m.Groups[1].Value;
  v = Regex.Replace(v, ",", "");
}
```

Comment: Seems above regex has extra parenthesis. Using `(?:^|[^w.,])(\d[\d,.]+)(?=\W|$)` will also match "h25" in the string "joe.smith25 ($3,004.50)"

Answer (score 1):

The approach of removing offending characters is potentially problematic. What if there's another `.` in the string somewhere? It won't be removed, though it should!

Removing non-digits or periods, the string `joe.smith ($3,004.50)` would transform into the unparseable `.3004.50`.

Imho, it is better to match a specific pattern, and extract it using a group. Something simple would be to find all contiguous commas, digits, and periods with regexp:

```
[\d,\.]+
```

Sample test run:

```
Pattern understood as:
[\d,\.]+
Enter string to check if matches pattern
>  a2.3 fjdfadfj34  34j3424  2,300 adsfa    
Group 0 match: "2.3"
Group 0 match: "34"
Group 0 match: "34"
Group 0 match: "3424"
Group 0 match: "2,300"
```

Then for each match, remove all commas and send that to the parser. To handle case of something like `12.323.344`, you could do another check to see that a matching substring has at most one `.`.

Comment: This regex matches everything.

Comment: It now matches everything except `""`.

Comment: The concept you're proposing would require a complex regex that is difficult to read and debug. It may be better to break it down into steps with several regex and conditionals. I could provide an answer (although written in Ruby as I don't know c#.

Comment: @mindriot Point taken. I changed it to something more transparent.

Comment: By send to parser, do you mean either `Single.Parse()` or `Single.TryParse`?