# String to int formatexception

Tags: c#, .net

In php I could do something like this:

```
if (balance == 0 && !neverBought)
```

Where balance comes from an API and is a string.

In C# I tried to convert balance to int as shown below:

```
if (int.Parse(balance) == 0 && !(neverBought))
```

But I get Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the value of `balance`.

Comment: try [TryToParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method

Comment: In PHP, any string prefixed with a number is considered a number for all practical purposes. In C#, Parse only works with strings that contain only numeric characters.

Comment: Are you sure the contents of balance is an integer?  A name like balance leads me to think it might be a decimal instead

Comment: Of course, if you're relying on the behavior that @zneak mentioned, instead of treating such a string as an invalid number, you should *really* fix that.

Comment: balance = "4.99". So, it is not integer for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not sure if the string is valid use a method such as `TryParse` to attempt to parse it without throwing an exception:

Based on comments you also don't have an integer, you have a decimal value, so you should parse it as one as well.

```
decimal decimalBalance;
if(decimal .TryParse(balance, out decimalBalance) 
    && decimalBalance == 0m && !neverBought)
```

Comment: The approach suggested by @Servy is absolutely correct.  You SHOULD use TryParse if you are uncertain of your input.  However, I suspect you are suffering from the input string not being a number because coming from PHP, you are probably passing in some value like "$1,999.99" or similar where the '$' or the ',' are causing the problem.  I think you need a "RemoveNonNumeric(this string s)" extension method.  The basic approach with a Regex is discussed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055742/regex-to-remove-all-non-numeric-or-period

Comment: @Eric You can simply provide an appropriate formatter to the third parameter of `TryParse`, based on one of the common formats, rather than using regexes which are generally rather fragile and harder to ensure the correctness of.

Comment: @Servy - I was unaware of this, so you got me curious.  I'm providing a link to the docs/example for that overload just as a quick reference for anybody else that wants an easy look.  MSDN:http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ew0seb73.aspx.  On cool thing I noticed is that it also includes a NumberStyles flags parameter that can allow currency characters WIHTOUT any need to strip them.  Slick!  Thanks for pointing that out.  You're also correct about the Regex.  Very culture specific.  For example, in some cultures 1.345,978 should parse to the decimal 1345.978.

Answer (score -1):

Convert.ToInt32() would probaly help aswell if you are sure balance isn't a string

```
            string a = "3";
            int b = 3;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(a) == b)
            {
                //do smth
            }
```